# Modify the actual variable passed to a function

Tags: java, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I have the following code to reassign the variable `ll1` inside the `balance` function. But this is not visible in the main function. This is probably because it's the local copy that is getting reassigned. The original memory location remains intact.

How could I modify it so that the actual `ll1` gets modified?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Node ll2 = new Node();
   Node ll1 = new Node();
   balance(ll1,ll2);
}
private static void balance(Node ll1, Node ll2) {
   int size1=size(ll1);
   int size2=size(ll2);
   if(size1==size2){

   } else if(size1>size2){
       // add size1-size2 zeros as prefix to ll2
       ll2=addNodes(ll2,size1-size2);

   } else if(size1<size2){
       // add size2-size1 zeros as pre
    ll1=addNodes(ll1,size2-size1);
   }
}

private static Node addNodes(Node node, int num) {
    int count = 0;
    Node node1 = null;
    Node node2 = node;
    while (count < num) {
        node1 = new Node();
        node1.value = 0;
        node1.next = node2;
        node2 = node1;
        count++;
    }
    return node1;
}
```

Comment: You’re confusing the local reference with referenced object. You can modify the *content* of the local reference all you want—with the caveat that doing so can be confusing. Note that `addNodes` isn’t really doing what you think, in addition to setting each new node’s `next` to the node passed in, which seems incorrect. It might be worth taking a step back and tracing through what your code is (a) actually doing, and (b) making sure you understand what it’s *supposed* to be doing.

Comment: @DaveNewton, yeah, you are right. I will check. I wanted to add some zeros to the prefix

Comment: `Node nll2 = new Node();
   Node nll1 = new Node();
   balance(ll1,ll2);`  the `balance(ll1,ll2);` call wont compile, as no variables with the names `ll1` and `ll2` dont exist there

Comment: Are you trying to implement a singly-linked-list?

Answer (score 1):

Function parameter passing is a one-way operation, which means you can't edit the parameter passed to you

But when what you need to edit is **NOT** in the parameter list, that becomes possible

For example, create a wrapper class:

```
public class NodePair {
  public final Node n1;
  public final Node n2;
  public NodePair(Node a, Node b) { n1 = a; n2 = b; }
}
```

When this gets passed to you, you can't modify the pair, but you can modify n1 and n2 through the pair

Comment: Yeah, that works. Is that the only way, or could there be a better way. It somewhat feels weird to make a special wrapper class for such a simple thing

Comment: @rohit The better way is to **NOT** let functions modify local variables. It is not recommended in java

Comment: @rohit Another way: If you pass basic types by wrapper objects (like `Integer` instead of `int`), you are actually passing its reference so you can modify it in the function. This does not apply to some "final" objects (like `String`, you can never edit a `String` but re-creating one)